# multiple arguments for ng-class not working

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have two parameters I'm trying to check to set a class with ng-class, but for some reason it will only work with one.

Here is my code:

```
ng-class="{'alert-viewed':item.viewed && item.status <= 0}
```

If is just us 'alert-viewed':item.viewed it works. But adding on the item.status check breaks it.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: what are typical values for `item.status`?  is `-1` a common value?  and why would you use numbers to represent status anyway?  Looking at this more closely, you probably need parens around the second half of the statement, something like `item.viewed && (item.status <= 0)`

Comment: API sets a default value of 0. The typical values are ints. Status has up to 4 states. Now, to the original question... any insight? I can imagine other scenarios where one would have an expression with more than one argument to set a class.

Comment: did the parens not help?  right now, the `&&` is being evaluated first, so it's `item.viewed && item.status` is evaluated and then compared to `<=0`.  what you want is `item.viewed` evaluated separately from  `(item.status <=0)`, I assume....

Comment: Thanks, Claies. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of operations is wrong in your expression.  Because `&&` has a higher precedence than `<=`, your flags are being evaluated first, then compared to `<=0`.  Instead, you want the second half of your expression to be evaluated first, *and then* evaluated against the first half, which means you need parenthesis around the second half of the statement.

```
ng-class="{'alert-viewed':item.viewed && (item.status <= 0)}
```